# How to display GeoTIFF in browser as true color

Tags: geotiff-tiff, browser

There is a [library](https://github.com/geotiffjs/geotiff.js/) which can load and display (with a help of other library) GeoTIFF files. However I did not find example how to display them in true (natural) color

Comment: https://geotiffjs.github.io/ has some examples. What have you already tried? What was the result? What did you expect to happen instead?

Comment: Do you mean that you are now seeing unnatural colors? What kind of TIFF do you have?, How many bands, what is the bit depth?

Comment: All I got were images like this one https://easyupload.io/dd6b9m and not true color like in demo application like this one https://easyupload.io/0euzfw. Looking for an example how to achieve true color without having to dig in source of https://geotiffjs.github.io.

Comment: Seems like a satellite image or false color infrared. That could mean that the bands are not in red, green, blue order and what you see is normal. Do you see the same image in natural colors with some other viewer, like QGIS?

Comment: I do not have the GeoTIFF file anymore but the data was satellite images as I saw it in true/natural colors with QGIS